# centring content/text in absolute div absolute; transform from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the content to be vertically centred in the parent div (full width). It currently transitions/transforms properly, but it is centred in the screen with the left side of the content.

The content is dynamic (sample text used) so I don't have full control over its width. (the page looks blank but when moused over text appears near center)

```
<article id="..." class='col-md-12' >

    <div class="lg-indx-img" 
        <a href="#" class="linkage"></a>

        <div class="cat-icn">
          <p>dynamic sample text</p> /* this text is just a sample, my text is brought in through  <?php the_title(); ?> etc */
        </div>

        <div class="cover"></div>
    </div>

</article>
```

Link:

[codepen.io/anon/pen/doRmJJ](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doRmJJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this into your `.cat-icn` style block: `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`. This should bring it dead center.

Comment: Yup. I was just gonna say that. This is the answer. Make sure to use some prefixes for older browsers.

Comment: what are the preferred prefixes

Comment: @user3550879, [Link](http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms) & [Link](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Comment: adding that doesn't seem to affect my code, remember I am using sample text, the text is brought in dynamic, so the width changes. It screws with the transform origin. It works with defined text, not dynamic

Comment: you sure about that? seems to work for me: [Forked pen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/oXwyqb).

Comment: @user3550879, hang on, did you mean centred horizontally & vertically to the parent div which is `lg-indx-img` and which is full-width & full-height it seems?

Comment: @user3550879 If above is the case then instead of having `position: absolute;` on your `.cat-icn` style block, you will have to use `position: relative;`.

Comment: I need .cat-icn to be positioned absolute so that I can z-index it over other elements. The div is vertical and horiz centred in article/lg-img (both are full screen) My issue is that when using dynamic text it doesn't 'grow' from the center, rather than the left-side of the div is centred and it grows to the right. The sample text works, but I can't put in <?php the_title(); ?> in my example cause it would show anything

Comment: my apology I managed to fix it by putting it inside another div, thank you for your help